# How to make a file image of a pertition and mount it in linux?

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, disk-image, ddrescue

My problem is that I have cloned a 500GB hard drive into a 1 TB hard drive and now I need an image copy of the first partition in order to work with it.

Now to clone the entire 1TB hard drive into an image would be an overkill since I only need the 500 GB partition in it.

Any ideas?

BTW im not sure how to mount this image moreover when I would not have it's master block device.

Solutions involving ddrescue are prefered to dd.

Comment: Why are you asking about ddrescue when you say that you already have the image?

Comment: Because what I have is a master copy of a disk that is failing in the form of another disk.

Now I figured out that it would be more simple and safe to work with image files inside a filesystem instead of blocks and partitions, since I can use cp with ease instead of dd every time I need a copy. It is also safer because I make sure not to overwrite anty partiionIt andcould even be faster!

What I'm not sure is if I could use ddrescue to copy only the partition and how would I mount it,

Comment: Tell dd or ddrescue to copy the partition's block device instead of the whole disk's block device.  i.e. instead of `ddrescue /dev/sda /path/to/outfile`, use `ddrescue /dev/sda1 /path/to/outfile`.    If you really want to save disk space, you might want to consider using compressed qcow image files rather than raw image files - i.e. use `qemu-img` (form the qemu-utils package) rather than dd or ddrescue.  qcow image files can be mounted with `qemu-nbd` (also from qemu-utils) or `qcow-mount` (from libqcow-utils).

Comment: Thanks. I was already doing ddrescue  /dev/sda1 /path/to/outfile but now I have some guarantee that it will work. I have 2 TB empty disk so I think that 4 or 5 copies will be more than enough to figure out what's going on with my partition.

Comment: please write a summary of what you did as an answer and then accept it, so that this question is flagged as answered.

Comment: I'm still on the process, ddrescue says 68% so not yet may be